# Apache Alias to access folder in different harddrive? (localhost)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, alias

Installed Appserv. Made a php.

D:/Appserv/www/x/y/file.php

Then I have a folder, like "E:/foldie"

I want file.php to mess with that folder. I found this somewhere:
`<IfModule mod_alias.c>`
`Alias /foldie/ "E:/foldie"`
`<Directory "E:/foldie">`
`Options Indexes MultiViews`
`AllowOverride None`
`Order allow,deny`
`Allow from all`
`</Directory>`
`</IfModule>`

So I added it to my httpd.config file.Then I added the following to file.php:

`echo(realpath("../../foldie/"));`

Was expecting `"G:/foldie"`. Nothing happened.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

The `Alias` Directive is for apache to serve files from a different directory, it is separate to php code running on the apache server.

Comment: I want a .php to read the files in another drive. I want to configure apache to le tme.

Comment: Well, you can't configure apache to do this, you'll have to write php to do it.

Comment: @navand tell us *what* you want to do, not how you think you can do it!